# Renovação AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, apple

Olá,
Eu queria lançar uma aplicação mas quando fui ao membership da Apple dizia que estava expirado....então eu renovei e agora não consigo adicionar a aplicação.
Alguém sabe quanto tempo tenho que esperar para que o meu Developer Membership fique atualizado ou renovado?

Answer (score 1):

O prazo maximo que eles dao pra renovacao 'e de 48 horas e, quando demora mais que isso (ou quando voce precisa agilizar o processo), da pra mandar email ou ligar pra Apple que os atendentes resolvem rapidinho. Os dados pra contato voce pode encontrar nessa pagina aqui: [Apple contact](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta